# Unicode input retrieved via PrimeFaces input components become corrupted

Tags: jsf, unicode, primefaces, character-encoding, mojibake

When I was still using PrimeFaces v2.2.1, I was able to type unicode input such as Chinese with a PrimeFaces input component such as `<p:inputText>` and `<p:editor>`, and retrieve the input in good shape in managed bean method.

However, after I upgraded to PrimeFaces v3.1.1, all those characters become Mojibake or question marks. Only Latin input comes fine, it are the Chinese, Arabic, Hebrew, Cyrillic, etc characters which become malformed.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

#### Introduction

Normally, JSF/Facelets will set the request parameter character encoding to UTF-8 by default already when the view is created/restored. But if any request parameter is been requested *before* the view is been created/restored, then it's too late to set the proper character encoding. The request parameters will namely be parsed only once.

#### PrimeFaces encoding fail

That it failed in PrimeFaces 3.x after upgrading from 2.x is caused by the new `isAjaxRequest()` override in PrimeFaces' `PrimePartialViewContext` which checks a request parameter:

```
@Override
public boolean isAjaxRequest() {
    return getWrapped().isAjaxRequest()
            || FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().containsKey("javax.faces.partial.ajax");
}
```

By default, the `isAjaxRequest()` (the one of Mojarra/MyFaces, as the above PrimeFaces code has obtained by `getWrapped()`) checks the request header as follows which does not affect the request parameter encoding as request parameters won't be parsed when a request header is obtained:

```
    if (ajaxRequest == null) {
        ajaxRequest = "partial/ajax".equals(ctx.
            getExternalContext().getRequestHeaderMap().get("Faces-Request"));
    }
```

However, the `isAjaxRequest()` may be called by any phase listener or system event listener or some application factory *before* the view is been created/restored. So, when you're using PrimeFaces 3.x, then the request parameters will be parsed *before* the proper character encoding is been set and hence use the server's default encoding which is usually ISO-8859-1. This will mess up everything.

#### Solutions

There are several ways to fix it:

1. Use a [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) which sets [`ServletRequest#setCharacterEncoding()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setCharacterEncoding%28java.lang.String%29) with UTF-8. Setting the response encoding by [`ServletResponse#setCharacterEncoding()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setCharacterEncoding%28java.lang.String%29) is by the way unnecessary as it won't be affected by this issue.

   ```
   @WebFilter("/*")
   public class CharacterEncodingFilter implements Filter {

       @Override
       public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
           request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
           chain.doFilter(request, response);
       }

       // ...
   }
   ```

   You only need to take into account that `HttpServletRequest#setCharacterEncoding()` only sets the encoding for POST request parameters, not for GET request parameters. For GET request parameters you'd still need to configure it at server level.

   If you happen to use JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), such a filter is already provided out the box, [the `CharacterEncodingFilter`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/filters/CharacterEncodingFilter). Just install it as below in `web.xml` as first filter entry:

   ```
   <filter>
       <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   ```

   ---
2. Reconfigure the server to use UTF-8 instead of ISO-8859-1 as default encoding. In case of Glassfish, that would be a matter of adding the following entry to `<glassfish-web-app>` of the `/WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml` file:

   ```xml
   <parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8" />
   ```

   Tomcat doesn't support it. It has the `URIEncoding` attribute in `<Context>` entry, but this applies to GET requests only, not to POST requests.

   ---
3. Report it as a bug to PrimeFaces. Is there *really* any legitimate reason to check the HTTP request being an ajax request by checking a request parameter instead of a request header like as you would do for standard JSF and for example jQuery? The PrimeFaces' `core.js` JavaScript is doing that. It would be better if it has set it as a request header of `XMLHttpRequest`.

---

#### Solutions which do NOT work

Perhaps you'll stumble upon below "solutions" somewhere on the Internet while investigating this problem. Those solutions do won't ever work in this specific case. Explanation follows.

- Setting XML prolog:

  ```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
  ```

  This only tells the XML parser to use UTF-8 to decode the XML source before building the XML tree around it. The XML parser actually being used by Facelts is SAX during JSF [view build time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31890433/whats-the-view-build-time). This part has completely nothing to do with HTTP request/response encoding.
- Setting HTML meta tag:

  ```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  ```

  The HTML meta tag is ignored when the page is served over HTTP via a `http(s)://` URI. It's only been used when the page is by the client saved as a HTML file on local disk system and then reopened by a `file://` URI in browser.
- Setting HTML form accept charset attribute:

  ```
  <h:form accept-charset="UTF-8">
  ```

  Modern browsers ignore this. This has only effect in Microsoft Internet Explorer browser. Even then it is doing it wrongly. Never use it. All real webbrowsers will instead use the charset attribute specified in the `Content-Type` header of the response. Even MSIE will do it the right way as long as you do not specify the `accept-charset` attribute.
- Setting JVM argument:

  ```
  -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
  ```

  This is only used by the Oracle(!) JVM to read and parse the Java source files.

Comment: Thanks for this great post. I encountered this issue yesterday and already isolated it to `p:commandButton` before finding the filter solution. Your investigation proved it. This is a serious bug since the wrong encoded characters duplicated itself with every click on the save button.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have just tested your solutions today. The 2nd solution doesn't solve the problem. I also tried to use the `filter` but it didn't work out as well. Currently, there are 2 filters in my application: PrimeFaces's Fileupload Filter and my own filter. I added `HttpServletRequest#setCharacterEncoding()` into my own filter. If PrimeFaces's filter is called before the other one, will it cause the problem?

Comment: Your new problem seems to be solely related to using `System.out.println()` to print the submitted data. Is the stdout (there where the `System.out` will write to) also configured to use UTF-8? In Eclipse, you can set it in *Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text file encoding*. Please note that using **both** the filter and the server config isn't necessary. One of both is sufficient.

Comment: The DB persistence problem seems to be solely related to the character encoding the JDBC connection is using. Is it also configured to use UTF-8? MySQL for instance is known to incorrectly use the client platform encoding instead. Anyway to fix this and any future problems, please read http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html

Comment: @BalusC: Actually, I have followed that post and re-created the whole database using UTF-8 charset. However, I am stuck at the part where I have to set `useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8` for the JDBC connection. I have created my JDBC connection pool and JDBC resource using GlassFish admin console. Could you please tell me how I can apply the above 2 properties to my JDBC connections?

Comment: In the JDBC connection pool properties of the datasource entry in Glassfish admin console.