# PrimeFaces: UTF-8 bug related to file upload

Tags: jsf, file-upload, utf-8, jboss, primefaces

My web applications is currently using:

- JBoss AS7
- JSF2
- PrimeFaces

Due to this bug [UTF-8 form submit in JSF is corrupting data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721342/utf-8-form-submit-in-jsf-is-corrupting-data) I setup a **@WebFilter** doing

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

as suggested by BalusC (thank you).

In a simple  it always works right. I come to another problem when I need to use the same form for file upload, too (e.g. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/fileUploadDnd.jsf)

Here's the main difference

```
 <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

WITHOUT the enctype attribute, special unicode characters remains readable.

WITH the enctype attribute, I find "ciaÃ²" instead of "ciaò".

My filter `@WebFilter("/*") EncodingFilter` is always called however.

Could a possible solution be setting JBoss default encoding to utf-8? How can I do that?

*** * EDIT ****

I also tried putting -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 in my JAVA_OPTS but nothing.... it won't work :(( Please help me!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11206837/617373 , might help ya

Comment: nice but.... 1) what do you mean by "platform"? the os? jboss-as? how can I change the "default encoding"  2) I don't want to convert each of my form strings... what's the actual better solution? How can I modify primefaces? isn't there another way to go?

Comment: there is an explanation in that answer of what you should fix in primefaces jar in order to fix that issue (just saw that answer i don't really know if its exact issue as yours..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by another bug in PrimeFaces. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190081/primefaces-fileupload-filter-with-utf8-characters-filetr/11206837#11206837) for explanation and solution.

> *Could a possible solution be setting JBoss default encoding to utf-8? How can I do that?*

Yes. How to do that depends on JBoss version. In the ones who have a `server.xml` (until with version 6.x), it's a matter of adding `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` to the `<Connector>` element. In the ones who have a `standalone.xml` (7.x and newer), it's a matter of adding  `<property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING" value="UTF-8"/>` to the `<system-properties>` element.

Comment: It's not a problem for me. It's what I want.

Comment: But.... I just added <system-properties>
        <property name="file.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
        <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING" value="UTF-8"/>
    </system-properties> but it doesn't work

Comment: Hmm, that's probably another JBoss specific issue. What JBoss version exactly are you using?

Comment: I tried with <system-properties>
     <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING" value="UTF-8"/>
     <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.USE_BODY_ENCODING_FOR_QUERY_STRING" value="true"/>
</system-properties> too but nothing. My version is 7.1.1

Comment: It's not working, sadly... I ended up splitting in two forms: one for the upload and one for my data (the only one for which EncodingUTF8Filter is actually working)