# Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to implement example from Primefaces into WAB package.

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"    
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
          xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"  >
        <h:head>
            <ui:insert name="header">           
                <ui:include src="header.xhtml"/>         
            </ui:insert>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>

            <h1><img src="resources/css/images/icon.png" alt="NVIDIA.com" /> History Center</h1>
            <!-- layer for black background of the buttons -->
            <div id="toolbar" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1180px; height:30px; position:relative;  background-color:black">
                <!-- Include page Navigation -->
                <ui:insert name="Navigation">           
                    <ui:include src="Navigation.xhtml"/>         
                </ui:insert>

            </div>  

            <div id="logodiv" style="position:relative; top:35px; left:0px;"> 
                <h:graphicImage alt="Demo edit form"  style="position:relative; top:-20px; left:9px;"  value="resources/images/logo_linuxz.png" />
            </div>
            <div id="main" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:700px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:105px">

                <div id="mainpage" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:500px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:80px">

                    <div id="settingsHashMap" style="width:350px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:r; top:20px; left:1px">
                        <h:form id="test">

                            <p:barChart id="basic" value="#{LinuxController.categoryModel}" legendPosition="ne"
                                        title="Basic Bar Chart" min="0" max="200" style="height:300px"/>

                            <p:barChart id="horizontal" value="#{LinuxController.categoryModel}" legendPosition="se" style="height:300px"
                                        title="Horizontal Bar Chart" orientation="horizontal" min="0" max="200"/>

                            <p:barChart id="stacked" value="#{LinuxController.categoryModel}" legendPosition="ne" style="height:300px"
                                        title="Stacked Bar Chart" stacked="true" barMargin="50" min="0" max="300"/>


                        </h:form>


                    </div>   

                </div>  
            </div>

        </h:body>
    </html>

import org.glassfish.osgicdi.OSGiService;
import org.primefaces.model.chart.CartesianChartModel;
import org.primefaces.model.chart.ChartSeries;

// Update form example
@Named("LinuxController")
@SessionScoped
public class Linux implements Serializable {

    private CartesianChartModel categoryModel;

    public Linux() {
        createCategoryModel();

    }

    public CartesianChartModel getCategoryModel() {
        return categoryModel;
    }

    private void createCategoryModel() {
        categoryModel = new CartesianChartModel();

        ChartSeries boys = new ChartSeries();
        boys.setLabel("Boys");

        boys.set("2004", 120);
        boys.set("2005", 100);
        boys.set("2006", 44);
        boys.set("2007", 150);
        boys.set("2008", 25);

        ChartSeries girls = new ChartSeries();
        girls.setLabel("Girls");

        girls.set("2004", 52);
        girls.set("2005", 60);
        girls.set("2006", 110);
        girls.set("2007", 135);
        girls.set("2008", 120);

        categoryModel.addSeries(boys);
        categoryModel.addSeries(girls);
    }
}
```

When I try to access the JSF page the page is empty. I get this error in Glassfish log file:

```
[#|2012-06-06T20:53:47.931+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=321;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context /test, because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]

[#|2012-06-06T20:53:48.880+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=323;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context /test, because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]

[#|2012-06-06T20:53:52.714+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=321;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context /test, because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]

[#|2012-06-06T20:53:56.434+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=324;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context /test, because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]

[#|2012-06-06T20:53:57.591+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=322;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context /test, because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]

[#|2012-06-06T20:54:25.828+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=323;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context /test, because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]

[#|2012-06-06T20:54:26.912+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=321;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context /test, because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]

[#|2012-06-06T20:54:28.010+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=324;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context /test, because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]
```

How I can fix this problem? I suppose that this maybe caused by POM configuration?

Comment: Your new problem is a completely different one. Please do not reuse an existing question for this problem. Press `Ask Question` to create a new question for that. I think the Glassfish work directory is just dirty and you just need a full cleanup/rebuild.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

JSF/Facelets uses UTF-8 by default already which get set during restoring the view, however the PrimeFaces ajax view handler tries to access a request parameter before the view get restored, so the server's default character encoding will be used instead which is ISO-8859-1. You need to add the following entry to the `<glassfish-web-app>` of your `/WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml` file to instruct the Glassfish server to use UTF-8 as well:

```xml
<parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"/>
```

#### See also:

- [Unicode input retrieved via PrimeFaces input components become corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634230/typing-chinese-with-primefaces-editor-component)