# UTF-8 in PrimeFaces 3.x

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, utf-8

I have a very simple application,there is an inputtext in my index page and a button to go to page2.xhtml.

```
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:inputText value="#{mainBean.testValue}"/>
            <p:commandButton update="myoutput" value="ajax call" ajax="false"/>
            <p:separator />
            <h:commandButton action="#{mainBean.gotoPageTwo}" value="goto Page2"/>
            <br/>
            <h:outputText value="#{mainBean.testValue}" id="myoutput"/>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

I tested this application with PrimeFaces 2.2.1 and there was no problem.
but after submit each of the above button, my UTF-8 characters will destroy.
I tested [filter](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=19925) but it don't work.
Is it a bug in PrimeFaces 3.x?
Can any body solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to localise where the problem is? Does the appserver send UTF-8 to your browser, but the response headers say it's (e.g.) Latin1? Or does the appserver / framework convert your characters to to Latin1 before sending them to the browser?

Comment: I checked Content-Type with firebox and it was: text/html;charset=UTF-8. Notice that there is no problem with primefaces 2.2.1

Answer (score 5):

The `web.xml` example of the answer you found at PrimeFaces forum is incomplete. The `<filter-mapping>` is missing. Without that, the filter won't even run at all. Add it accordingly

```xml
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Character Encoding Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

When you're already on Servlet 3.0 (Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, etc), an alternative is to use just the [`@WebFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebFilter.html) annotation on the class. Don't forget to remove the filter entry from `web.xml`.

```
@WebFilter("/*")
```

For a background explanation of the cause of this character encoding problem during PrimeFaces 2.x-3.x upgrade, see also [Unicode input retrieved via PrimeFaces input components become corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634230/typing-chinese-with-primefaces-peditor-component)

Comment: You're right, yet my answer wasnt fully finished. I tend to edit multiple times (as do you) :)

Comment: Thanks. My problem solved. but in other application, in pages that there is primefaces fileupload, problem will appear. In fact I have two filter in web.xml and when there is p:upload in a page, character encoding filter don't work. How solve this?

Comment: Make sure that the character encoding filter is mapped before the PrimeFaces file upload filter in `web.xml`.