# primefaces fileupload filter with utf8 characters filter

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, utf-8, character-encoding, primefaces

I have a problem with utf-8 encoding in primefaces 3. but with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177319/probelm-with-utf8-in-primefaces-3-x) (adding filter for character encoding in web.xml), my problem solved. But I have another filter for primefaces fileupload in my web.xml. In pages that there is fileupload, even without uploading anything, my character encoding filter don't work and utf-8 character sets with unknown values, just like when there was no filter for uploading. How I can use this filter together?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a bug in PrimeFaces' `MultipartRequest`. It's using the platform default character encoding for form fields instead of the one set in the HTTP servlet request as done by `HttpServletRequest#setCharacterEncoding()` in your character encoding filter (which I assume is been mapped in `web.xml` *before* the PrimeFaces `FileUploadFilter`).

Basically, line 85 and 88 of `MultipartRequest` in PrimeFaces 3.3

```
formParams.get(item.getFieldName()).add(item.getString());
// ...
items.add(item.getString());
```

needs to be changed as follows

```
formParams.get(item.getFieldName()).add(item.getString(getCharacterEncoding()));
// ...
items.add(item.getString(getCharacterEncoding()));
```

I have reported it as [issue 4266](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4266). In the meanwhile, your best bet is to manually fix the incorrect string encoding in the backing bean action method as follows, assuming that the server platform default encoding is ISO-8859-1:

```
string = new String(string.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: addFormParam method doesn't have request parameter so i sent request parameter to this method as addFormParam(HttpServletRequest request, FileItem item) and i did what you told :  formParams.get(item.getFieldName())).add(item.getString(request.getCharacterEncoding()));
but it didn't work !!! what i can do?

Comment: I edited the answer, there's one more line which needs to be changed. The `request.` can be omitted, it's a `HttpServletRequestWrapper`.

Answer (score 5):

Essentially, you need the following line of code to fix this:

```
new String(file.getFileName().getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()), "UTF-8")
```