# Encoding issue while uploading file with primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, file-upload, character-encoding, primefaces

I have the same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546365/utf-8-text-is-garbled-when-form-is-posted-as-multipart-form-data).

I use primefaces 2.2 jsf implementation. I've tried all approaches, but works nothing. Is there another solution?
    When I try `new String (s.getBytes ("iso-8859-1"), "UTF-8");`,
how can I know input encoding?

Answer (score 4):

```
String fileName=new String(event.getFile()
                                 .getFileName()
                                 .getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()),"UTF-8").toUpperCase(locale);
```

Answer (score 1):

Input encoding is whatever your server is using as default encoding instead of UTF-8. So it is an application wide setting and thus not dependent on specific HTTP requests/clients. More than often it's just the same as [`Charset#defaultCharset()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset%28%29).

As to the concrete problem, note that also PrimeFaces 3.3 currently still struggles with this. See also [primefaces fileupload filter with utf8 characters filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190081) where you can find some hints to just hack the PrimeFaces source code itself to fix the bug.

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter this kind of problem when I was developing a japanese website. the text becomes unknown character. After some googling I was able to solve this.
here is my solution for this.

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8">
  <p:fileUpload id="image" immediate="true" auto="true" sizeLimit="1048576" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" fileUploadListener="#{uploadController.uploadListener}" mode="advanced" multiple="true"/>
</h:form>
```

you just have to add `multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8` in the enctype of your form.