# Cancel FileUpload when FileSizeMax is exceeded

Tags: java, jsf, file-upload, apache-commons, apache-commons-fileupload

I have a JSF application which runs in JBoss 6.1 which uses internal the 
Tomcat Servlet container.

I've realised the upload with apache commons file upload.
I want to prevent too large file uploads and have set the property 
`fileSizeMax` to 10MB within the class `FileUploadBase`. It works, the file 
upload throws an `FileSizeLimitExceededException` for all files larger than 
10MB. This exception throws within less than a second.
But the main problem is, that the whole file will be transferred over the 
network. I have found this out by checking the network traffic. Afterwards the redirect to the error page is done.

How can I interrupt the file transfer when the max size is exceeded 
without transferring the whole file? I assume that the file will be 
transferred in multiple packages because of the web form attribute `enctype
="multipart/form-data"`.

Comment: You mentioned in a comment in the answer that you're using PrimeFaces `<p:fileUpload>`. You should edit your question to state that you're using `<p:fileUpload>`, not that you're using Commons FileUpload (using `<p:fileUpload>` namely already implies for long that you're using Commons FileUpload "under the covers", note that it's thus merely an implementation detail).

Comment: PrimeFaces is just a detail which is not important beacause I'am using the native upload component from the brwoser without HTML5-JavaScript handling. I'am using a FileUploadFilter in my project which uses the commons file-upload classes to throw an Exception if maximal file size is exceeded.

Comment: Oh, then I wonder why you reinvented it instead of using `<p:fileUpload mode="simple">` which generates exactly the same HTML and does all the parsing and model-update job fully transparently?

Comment: I'am using the `<p:fileUpload mode="simple">` but I had to get the following Classes into my project because of an UTF-8 bug and to handle exceeding of the max file size. `org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter` and `org.primefaces.webapp.MultipartRequest`. Link to the utf-8 bug: http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3002

Comment: Right, the UTF-8 bug. It's fixed in 3.5 snapshot. See also http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3002 I've also reported it before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190081/primefaces-fileupload-filter-with-utf8-characters-filter As to max size, well, see the answer here below.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot abort a HTTP request halfway. If you did it, you would not be able to return a HTTP response and the client would end up with no form of feedback, expect maybe a browser-specific "Connection reset by peer" error page.

Your best bet is to validate it in JavaScript beforehand. This works by the way only in [browsers supporting HTML5 `File` API](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi). You didn't tell anything about which JSF file upload component you're using, so I have the impression that you just homebrewed one, so I'll give a generic answer which is applicable on the rendered HTML `<input type="file">` (note that it works as good on e.g. [Tomahawk's `<t:inputFileUpload>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418292/jsf-2-0-file-upload/5424229#5424229)):

```html
<input type="file" ... onchange="checkFileSize(this)" />
```

with something like this

```js
function checkFileSize(inputFile) {
    var max = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10MB

    if (inputFile.files && inputFile.files[0].size > max) {
        alert("File too large."); // Do your thing to handle the error.
        inputFile.value = null; // Clears the field.
    }
}
```

In case of older browsers not supporting this, well, you're lost. Your best alternative is Flash or Applet.

Comment: Hi, I'am using PrimeFaces and yes I'am using the simple file upload which means, that the native browser upload is used. I know the Html5-API solutions but for IE this works only in version 10.