# How to set character encoding on JSF resources in PrimeFaces app?

Tags: jsf, servlets, encoding, primefaces, websphere

I'm using **PrimeFaces 3.4** with **MyFaces 2.0.7** on **WebSphere 7**. I'm using filter to set the response encoding to UTF-8:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharsetEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

In logs I see the filter is called on each JSF resource set, including resoures such as:

```
http://localhost:9080/myapp/javax.faces.resource/myscript.js.xhtml?ln=mylib
```

However, when I see the response headers, charset is not set, only the `Contet-Type` is set to `application/x-javascript`. My filter is declared as first in web.xml, the only other I'm using is `org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter` which does nothing with character encoding.

The JavaScript files are treated as UTF-8 as default because messages are displayed correctly, but nevertheless I would like the character set to be set correctly.

How should I do that? The filter was always working for me, why not in JSF/PrimeFaces? Am I missing something with this approach?

Comment: No, I don't expect content type to be set because I know in this filter nothing about the possible content type. I can set only the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is some mess with your `<filter>`/`<servlet>` declaration

`Servlet` sould be

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and `Filter` should be

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Your filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.yourpackage.YourFilterClass</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Your filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Also, as you are using JSF the headers are set up in your views, most probably `*.xhtml` files. You can explicitly set character encoding there:

```
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF8" />
</h:head>
```

**Edit**

It was my misunderstanding of your question.

It seems that there is a bug in Primefaces stemming from use of `<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">`. `MultipartRequest` object uses platform's default encoding instead of encoding set on request object by a filter.

See [this answer for analysis and a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190081/primefaces-fileupload-filter-with-utf8-characters-filter). Another workaround is setting `UTF-8` as default encoding of your server.

Comment: Please read my question, the filter is working and is calling setCharacterEncoding, and I'm dealing with JavaScript resources, not jsf pages.

Comment: Pardon, my fault. I prefer using `<url-pattern>` in `<filter-mapping>`, so the initial wrong comment was born. It turns out that `setCharacterEncoding` is called in a filter, but is later ignored.

Comment: Yes, as if it was overwritten. For JSF pages the meta works, but for resources via outputScript the filter seems the only way, that is not functioning...

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. Basically, there are three ways of coping with the situation. 1. Set server encoding to UTF-8. 2. Follow the hacks of Primefaces, as suggested by BalusC. 3. Somehow use Primefaces' file upload component separately.