# PrimeFaces 3.3 <p:datatable> filtering fails with UTF8

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a PrimeFaces 3.3 / JSF application which I deploy to JBoss AS 7.1. To display my data I use a **p:dataTable** with some filtering headers. Here's the code (after narrowing down the sources):

```
<p:outputPanel id="custDataTable">            
        <p:dataTable var="item" value="#{customerController.items}" rowKey="#{item.id}"
                        selection="#{customerController.current}" selectionMode="single" id="customersTable">
            <p:column headerText="Surname" sortBy="#{item.surname}" filterBy="#{item.surname}" id="surname">  
                #{item.surname}
            </p:column>  
            <p:column headerText="Age" sortBy="#{item.age}" filterBy="#{item.age}" id="age" styleClass="age">
                #{item.age}
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="&nbsp;">
                <p:spacer width="20" height="0" />
                <p:commandButton update=":custForm" ajax="false" action="#{customerController.prepareEdit}" value="edit">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}" target="#{customerController.current}" />
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>  
</p:outputPanel>
```

PrimeFaces **p:dataTable** filtering on the numeric *Age* column always works but on the *Surname* column a strange behaviour arises. When the backing bean's **items** instance variable has elements with ASCII data in the *surname*, then filtering works. But when UTF8 data are present, then the filtering works only partially:

**[1]** I can type UTF8 characters of my locale in the column header field and the results are indeed filtered (that's the part that works).

**[2]** The backing bean's **current** instance variable is always null. I.e. the binding:

```
selection="#{customerController.current}"
```

doesn't seem to be working. I have added some logging in the **CustomerController::prepareEdit** method and the value is set to null when the *edit* **p:commandButton** is pressed. As a result, I can't edit an instance filtered on the basis of the *surname* column (when UTF8 data are present). However the same instance, with the same UTF8 data can be edited when I filter on the numeric *age* column, or when I don't filter at all.

To tackle the problem I tried registering a character encoding filter:

```
public class CharacterEncodingFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req,
                             ServletResponse resp,
                             FilterChain chain)
             throws IOException, ServletException {
        req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }
```

and registered it in my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app ...
...
  <filter>                                                                                                                                           
      <filter-name>Character Encoding Filter</filter-name>                                                                                           
      <filter-class>mp.util.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>                                                                                   
  </filter>      
</web-app>
```

but that didn't do the trick either.

Comment: Sure that the request character encoding is been set to UTF-8?

Comment: @BalusC: I've updated my question to also show what I tried to do with regard to the character encoding.

Comment: The filter mapping is missing. It's easier to use `@WebFilter("/*")` annotation. Btw: setting response character encoding is not necessary, JSF will do it properly. Only setting request character encoding is mandatory when using PrimeFaces, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634230/typing-chinese-with-primefaces-peditor-component/9839362#9839362

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I also only set the request character encoding as you advised.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to ensure that the request character encoding is been set to UTF-8. You can do that with a [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) which is been mapped on an URL pattern covering the requests of interest. E.g. `/*` or just on the servlet name of the `FacesServlet`.

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class CharacterEncodingFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    // ...
}
```

#### See also:

- [Unicode input retrieved via PrimeFaces input components become corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634230/typing-chinese-with-primefaces-peditor-component/9839362#9839362)