# Chinese Character Encoding of JSF input

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jsf, character-encoding

I am having a problem when trying to input and save a Chinese string into MySQL via JSF and Hibernate.

Actually, I used "System.out.print" and detected garbled words happened, after typing 我(me) in JSF input field but before saving to database. Here is part of the code:
index.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputText value="Input"/>
                <h:inputText value="#{showBean.input}" />
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:commandLink action="#{showBean.show()}" value="Show"/>

        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

ShowBean.java

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class showBean {
    String input;
    public showBean() {
        input = null;
    }

    public String getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    public void setInput(String input) {
        System.out.println("set input " + input);
        this.input = input;
    }

    public String show(){
        System.out.println("show input " + input);
        return "";
    }
}
```

The console output is :
set input ???è??è?????è??è?????
show input ???è??è?????è??è?????

Comment: Hi, I don't think people will be able to help you without showing some code. How are you inserting the data into the database?

Comment: You need to be more specific at which step exactly the character encoding fails. Is it garbled *before* saving in the DB? If not, is it garbled *while* saving in the DB? (thus, when you look in the DB by some admin tool). Etc.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the update. So, the HTTP request body encoding is wrong. First this, are you using JSP or Facelets as view technology? If Facelets, are you using a 3rd party component library like PrimeFaces? If so, are you sending a normal or an ajax request?

Comment: I just use normal facelets, and I didn't use primefaces here, and sending a normal request. I want to see what I get from the input box, but it is garble after submitting the form

Comment: Okay, then the cause is not Facelets as it uses by default UTF-8. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you're indeed using Facelets (which uses UTF-8 by default) and are not using PrimeFaces ajax ([which is known to messup request body encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634230/typing-chinese-with-primefaces-peditor-component)), your problem has 2 causes:

1. MySQL JDBC driver character encoding is not been set to UTF-8. This caused garbled characters in the DB.
2. Eclipse console character encoding is not been set to UTF-8. This caused garbled characters in `System.out`.

The solutions are:

1. Add `useUnicode=yes` and `characterEncoding=UTF-8` parameters to the JDBC connection. You can specify it either as query string in the JDBC URL

   ```
   jdbc:mysql://hostname:3306/db_name?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
   ```

   or as connection properties in JDBC datasource, exactly the same way as you specified username, password, etc.
2. Tell Eclipse to use UTF-8 as console encoding by *Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text File Encoding*:

   [image]

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Comment: I really appreciate your detailed answer.

Comment: I tried your way and other similar solutions many times, BUT I identified the problem is not about the MYSQL and Hibernate, but about the JSF input box. Sorry about the confusion! As you have seen the code I provided above, this is a new and simple Netbean project I created to identify the problem, and it doesn't has database connection. At last, the console show garbed words after I typed a chinese word and clicked "show" in index. How can I fix this input problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you use glassfish just add the following code to glassfish-web.xml

```
<glassfish-web-app>
   <parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8" />
</glassfish-web-app>
```